# Is there any tool which can help me to convert the data from the Java Swing code to a Template file?

Tags: java, swing, templates

I have designed a text areas based form using Swing and when I enter the data into the text fields and when I click on the submit button, I want that data to be converted into a template file in xml format. Are there any tool which I can be helpful for this purpose ?

Thanks
Navneet

Answer (score 1):

none that i know...
here's how i'd do it:

1. create a java bean that holds your data
2. use something like [jgoodies binding](http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/libraries.html) to bind an instance of your bean above to a gui form. its pretty trivial to do for anything that isnt a table or tree-table.
3. use something like [simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) to serialize your bean to xml.